# How to compare two string in foreach loop of jsp/jstl?

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

I have the need to compare to strings in foreach loop.

My development environment:

1) MAC 10.11,

2) STS Version: 3.7.3.RELEASE

4) Spring Web MVC,

5) Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1

```
<c:set var="day" scope="session" value="${day}_${curId}"/>
<c:set var="new_day" scope="session" value="${2_456123}"/>


<c:if test="${day eq new_day}">
    <p> Both are same.      
</c:if>
```

But the system get hags at the line

```
<c:if test="${day eq new_day}">
```

Can somebody give any pointer ?

Thanks & Regards,

Arun Dhwaj

Comment: Try using <c:set var="new_day" scope="session" value="2_456123"/>

Comment: What do you mean "get hags" ? Also, you're missing the closing `</p>` tag

Comment: Typo, it should be:

"the system get hangs at the line".

Comment: Thanks @rickz for you response.

But its not helping, in general cases like:

<c:set var="new_day" scope="session" value="${day}_${accountId}"/>.

It will be great if you share your thought.

Comment: What do you mean by "get hangs"? Can you tell us the exact problem/error you are facing/getting?

Comment: @Angelo Oparah, I've mentioned clearly, how to compare two dynamic string in JSP using JSTL. Can you please focussed on it.

Comment: Hey no need to get offended: I simply requested to clarify what is the error you are getting? Can you point me towards the section of your post where you clearly state what error you get when you attempt to compare those strings? Because I still can't find it. Cheers

Comment: When I'm trying to do the following. Its not working in jsp. 

<c:set var="day" scope="session" value="${day}_${curId}"/>
<c:set var="new_day" scope="session" value="mon_645123"/>


<c:if test="${day eq new_day}">
 <p> Both are same.  
</c:if>

Comment: Ok I was referring to any error message, but nvm I probably found the issue. I will post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is demonstration code.

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="day" scope="session" value="2"/>
<c:set var="curId" scope="session" value="456123"/>
<c:set var="day" scope="session" value="${day}_${curId}"/>
<c:set var="new_day" scope="session" value="2_456123"/>
<c:if test="${day eq new_day}">
     Both are same.      
</c:if>
```

that prints: Both are the same.
If I change line number 5 to

```
<c:set var="new_day" scope="session" value="${2_456123}"/>
```

which is what you posted, then I get an error message
contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${2_456123}]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is caused by the following assignment

```
<c:set var="day" scope="session" value="${day}_${curId}"/>
```

With the above line you are assigning to the var `day` a value that comes from another variable with the same name but not necessarily with the same `scope`. In other words you might have already a variable called `day` that lives in another scope.

The default scope is the page scope, then you have *in order* the request, session and application therefore if a variable with the name `day` is retrieved in the page or request scope that variable will be considered when you perform the test and the variable you have defined in the session scope will be ignored.

You have two options

1. Change the name of the variable defined in the session scope and use that name when performing the test

   ```
   <c:set var="niceday" scope="session" value="${day}_${curId}"/>

   <c:if test="${niceday eq ...}">
   ```
2. Specify the scope of the variable used in the c:if tag

   ```
   <c:if test="${sessionScope.day eq ...}">
   ```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks @Angelo for your response. But the problem is this.

To make it simple, 

Consider any two dynamic string [ the string you getting at runtime]

say,

<c:set var="str1" scope="page" value="${user1.getName()}"/>

<c:set var="str2" scope="page" value="${user2.getName()}"/>

Now, have to compare these "str1" and "str2". If both are equal, then take action-1, else take action-2.

The problem is JSP <c:if > test is not taking two dynamic string.

<c:if test="${str1 eq str2}">
.....

It will grate if you have some thought here.

Thanks in advance.

Arun Dhwaj

Comment: @ArunDhwajIIITH I can't see anything wrong in what you have just written. Do you get any error message or any runtime error at all?